# My /etc/init.d/apache2 restart failed

Tags: apache2

after I installed the mail server and tried to restart Apache2, an error occurred.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx0at.png)

Then I open systemctl apache2.service status.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuGEn.png)

What should i do? Please Help!!

Comment: You should read the log entries that were shown on the screen and in your image.

Comment: And you should post the text here, not links to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see log:

```
syntax error on line 222 of /etc/apache2/...
```

The setting file is incorrect.

Comment: What should I change?